# Timer.schedule api: Why the timer task executes even the first time has passed

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have set firstTime as today 15:35 but and then once per day. But when I start the application today even after 15:35, it starts the task immediately . I don't want that.

```
 public void scheduleTimerTask() {

        int taskStartTimeInSec = 56100;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, taskStartTimeInSec);
        Date firstTime = today.getTime();
        System.out.println("firstTime is : "+ firstTime);
            timer.schedule(new Task(), firstTime,
                        1000*60*60*24);
    }

    class Task extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
           System.out.println("Thread Invoked at "+ new Date());

        }

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.scheduleTimerTask();
        }


    Output : 
    firstTime is : Thu Sep 15 15:35:00 IST 2016
    Thread Invoked at Thu Sep 15 18:33:35 IST 2016
```

I want that if I start later (may be at 16:00) then today the task should not execute, but it should execute tomorrow at 15:35. Because today the 15:35 time has passed.

kindly help.

Comment: You should not use `set(Calendar.SECOND, taskStartTimeInSec)` like that. The value for SECOND is supposed to be the second of a minute, so within 0-59

Comment: Calendar i am using just to get today's date. It is working fine. You can see the today's date with time in seconds specified. Check the output firstTime is : Thu Sep 15 15:35:00 IST 2016.  More that 59 seconds value will move the clock forward in minutes,hours and so on . for example 15*3600 + 35*60 = 56100 will result clock value as 15:35:00 as shown in my code.

Comment: You could check if firstTime is in the past, and if it is, then add one day to it before scheduling.

Comment: Yes ..that can work thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Gustav suggestion:

```
public void scheduleTimerTask() {

        int taskStartTimeInSec = 56100;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, taskStartTimeInSec);
        Date firstTime = today.getTime();
        if(firstTime.before(new Date())){
            today.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            firstTime = today.getTime();
        }
        System.out.println("firstTime is : "+ firstTime);
            timer.schedule(new Task(), firstTime,
                        1000*60*60*24);
    }
```

Above worked fine. Now if the first time is before I am adding a day hence it will invoke next day only.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own solution if it works :)